# Why is jQuery select DOM replacing rather than appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> I want to create a single select DOM and append it multiple time with different attributes. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var select = $('<select></select>').attr('class', 'form-control input-sm serial_no');
            select.append('<option value="hello">Hello</option>');
            $('#foo').append(select.attr('id','one'));
            $('#foo').append(select.attr('id','two'));
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

**It is only appending one select with id two. How can I achive it?**

Comment: There is only one copy of the `select`.  So you append it, then when you try to append it again, it removes the first instance, then does the append again.  You need two instances of the select --either by creating two elements or use the `clone` mentioned @somani in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone it and appent that

```
select.clone(true)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var select = $('<select></select>').attr('class', 'form-control input-sm serial_no');
            select.append('<option value="hello">Hello</option>');
            debugger
            $('#foo').append(select.clone(true).attr('id','one'));
            $('#foo').append(select.clone(true).attr('id','two'));
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I am clonning with true `clone(true)` if you have event with your element it will also clone events you can remove `true` from the clone if not required

Answer (score 1):

It is not appending because it is the same element. You are just changing the attribute of the element and appending again, but the element is the same. You have to create another select element and append it

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var select = $('<select></select>').attr('class', 'form-control input-sm serial_no');
            select.append('<option value="hello">Hello</option>');
             var select1 = $('<select></select>').attr('class', 'form-control input-sm serial_no');
            select1.append('<option value="hello">Hello</option>');
            $('#foo').append(select.attr('id','one'));
            $('#foo').append(select1.attr('id','two'));
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div></body>
```